# Two paths under the same package in bintray

Tags: android, maven, android-library, bintray, jcenter

I have successfully uploaded a library to bintray, which shows the version and the dependency correctly. But when I requested to link it to jcenter, I got this response:

> Hi,
>
> We can see that there are two paths under the same package, one used for the *.aar/.jar/.apk and jar*-sources.jar and *-javadoc.jar files on under: 
>   /com/androiddev/android-dev-core/1.0.0
>
> and one for the .pom file: 
>   /com/androiddev/core/1.0.0
>
> We can only approve one path for a single package. 
>   Please consolidate the two paths and let us know which path prefix you would like to include.
>
> Thanks, 
>   JFrog Support

I can see the two paths under file section in bintray. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid this problem make sure your library name is similar to the one you have created on bintray. If they differ, it will create two separate paths when you upload your library to bintray from android studio terminal using bintrayUpload command.

My bintray configuration in build.gradle is given below.

```
ext {
bintrayRepo = 'dev' //the maven repo name (created on bintray)
bintrayName = 'android-dev-core' //the name you want to give at your project on bintray
orgName = 'thisisjatinrana' //your user name

publishedGroupId = 'com.jatin' //aaaa : the librairy group
artifact = 'android-dev-core' //BBBB : the library name
libraryVersion = "1.0.0" //the librairy version

//the library will be : aaaa:BBBB:version

libraryName = 'android-dev-core'
libraryDescription = 'Android essential building blocks to speed up development process'

siteUrl = 'https://github.com/thisisjatinrana/AndroidDevCore'
gitUrl = 'https://github.com/thisisjatinrana/AndroidDevCore.git'

developerId = 'jatinrana'
developerName = 'Jatin Rana'
developerEmail = 'thisisjatinrana@gmail.com'

licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
```

}

Here artifact and bintray project name should be same as your library name in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If your lib and artifact have different name,  you will see there will be two folders in bintray's file section. Pom files and jar files will be in different folder. To avoid this, you should rename your artifact and your lib(module) as same.

I think that bintray project name can be different. It is optional. Artifact and module name equality will be enough. You will see your pom files and jar files in same folder after build your project.